# how to easily create a unit test to an existing method in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

as posted here:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748493/missing-funtionality-of-creating-a-new-unit-test-from-editor

there is no automatic way to add UT to existing code

> Posted by doronneu on 6/14/2012 at 4:53 AM So How do I add new tests
>   to an existing testing project without coding them manually? Posted by
>   Microsoft on 6/14/2012 at 4:48 AM Hi,

.

> The Test-> New Test menu was intentionally removed. In Visual Studio
>   2012, we have rearchitected the Unit Test framework to make it more
>   extensible. Thus we have adapters for nUnit/xUnit etc built already
>   along with the in-box mstest.
>
> The 'New Test' menu does not have any extension points where 3rd party
>   adapters can plug-in. Therefore we decided to remove it. We moved all
>   the New Test Project types into the File -> New -> Project dialog.

Is there any workarround (resharper?) that enable adding UT to existing methods?

Comment: It depends on what you want to test. Database, Service methods, Controllers, UI? They all require different setups.

Comment: Writing unit tests by some wizard, in an automatic way, is probably worse than not writing unit tests at all.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Exactly. Writing tests to meet testing requirements to make the project look good wouldn't really accomplish the goal of testing.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov the wizard only writes placeholders. It generates all the basic tempalte code to write UT (mainly signature). It helps me write the real logic faster.

Comment: In a properly architected application you write the unit tests before writing the actual code. So I don't really see how an automated wizard would be able to generate any placeholders for you - you don't even have written the actual code yet. So, yeah, if you have the habit of writing unit tests **after** you have written the code, such feature might be useful to you. My point was just that this is not the standard way of doing Test Driven Development.

Comment: Please see http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2748862-add-create-unit-tests-menu-option-back- and add your vote if you feel that the automatic generation of "skeleton" code is important as we are reviewing that user voice idea.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov TDD is not the only methodology that involves unit testing. as such, writing tests before code is **not** the only proper way to program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround I've found for Unit Testing in VS2012 is to go back to VS2010!

They are generally project-compatible, so jumping back and forth between the two versions of VS generally works very well (for C# projects).

The unit testing support in VS2012 has been butchered and is totally unfinished - how it was released in this terrible state is beyond me. (given how much we pay per licence, it's outrageous!) In 2010 you could easily get it to create all the boilerplate code you needed for a unit test, but that has all gone from 2012. In 2010 you could run your tests and see the progress. Gone, all gone - in 2012 you have no idea what is happening (if anything). In 2010 you would get results from the test run and have some idea of what happened. In 2012 it gives you an incomplete list of lies and then you check in your "passing" code and start swearing when your build server falls over with many failed tests that 2012 just swept under the carpet. In conclusion: my opinion is simply "Don't do unit testing in 2012, use 2010".

Hopefully VS 2013 is not long off, and they will have had a chance to implement unit testing support in it.

Comment: Does anyone know of a Visual Studio extension that will just run all of the 750+ unit tests that I've already created under VS2008 and VS2010?  I really don't want to waste time rewriting all of these regressions and unit tests -- I want something that will work within the Visual Studio 2012/13 IDE and won't cost two arms and a leg to implement (the arms being "I'm not going to waste two or three weeks rewriting this from scratch", and the leg as "Not going to shell out $20K to MS for something that they should have left in VS in the first place").

Comment: We've been looking at nCrunch which seems really good (it runs your tests in the background so you get an indication as you type when you've broken a test). Note that we've also discovered that a lot of the VS2010 UI for creating unit tests is still in VS2012, but no longer exposed on the menus - you have to bind hotkeys to the commands to expose them. So it's a little but better than it appeared when I posted the answer above. But still pretty dismal.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I re-read your question and looked at the "MS Issue Post" it does look like they've moved the standard menu layout a bit. Also according to it there is no workaround and you need to contact MS support site regarding this.

However, there is enough information [here](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/learn/code/3rd-party-unit-tests-plugin-in-vs/) to install a NUnit and start writing your tests. This still does not mean automatic though.